# Scraping pdf files with PyPDF2 and appending regex lists into Dataframe

Tags: python, generator

I am looping through pdf files, using regex search and findall to append list type data into a dataframe. I export to excel for end user to easily search info. Below is method breakdown of this script:

- Find pdf files in folder and delete duplicate files
- Define regex compile objects outside of loop.
- Growinglist() generator as workaround for pandas dataframe
- Use for loop to iterate through pdf files and create dataframe of equal length lists.
- Append to DataFrame df1.
- export to xlsx excel file for end user

Below are some sample strings after being joined:

```
output1 = '''ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCELICENCE NO : 1314824TRANSPORT MANAGEMENT CENTRE (TMC)Phone:  Monday To Friday 8.30 AM - 4.30 PMTo activate and deactivate your approved work shift(s) on your Road Occupancy Licence, please visit: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au. This licenceis for the occupation of the road space only. If you are unable to access myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au, please call TMC on 1800 679 782. Forfurther assistance, please refer to the proponent's user manual here: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au/help.pdfNON DEVELOPMENT - NOT KNOWNProject:WestConnex 3BThis Activity :LFR001-WB-CONTRA-Cecil to Justin ATS-WCX-3B 005LOCATIONSubject Road:LILYFIELD RDFrom:GORDON ST, ROZELLETo:GROVE ST, LILYFIELDCouncil:INNER WESTLICENSEEOrganisation:John HollandRef No:Name:Ismat ZahraPhone:0419919046ONSITE CONTACTName:Mitchell EversonPhone:0428877584TRAFFIC MANAGEMENTFlow Management:Contra Flow; Standard Lane MergeClosure Type:All lanes one directionClosure Lane(s):ShoulderDirection(s):Eastbound and WestboundLICENCE DURATIONFrom:01-Dec-2019To:31-Jan-2020LICENCE CONDITIONS1YOU MUST USE SHIFT ACTIVATION WEB ADDRESShttps://myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au TO ACTIVATE AND DEACTIVATE YOURAPPROVED ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCE(S). (TO CHANGE TRAFFICCONTROL SIGNALS TO FLASHING YELLOW OR TO ACTIVATEPERMANENT VARIABLE MESSAGE SIGNS DIAL 1800 679 782)2THIS LICENCE IS NOT AN APPROVAL OF THE PROPONENT'S TRAFFICCONTROL PLAN. PLEASE NOTE WORKCOVER REQUIRES THATTRAFFIC CONTROL PLANS COMPLY WITH AS1742.33ALL MATTERS RELATING TO NOISE GENERATION OR OTHERENVIRONMENTAL FACTORS ON SITE ARE UNDER THE JURISDRICTIONOF THE LOCAL COUNCIL AND/OR THE ENVIRONMENTAL PROTECTIONAUTHORITY.4SHOULD THE PROPOSED WORKS INVOLVE UNDERBORING OREXCAVATION OF STATE ROAD ASSETS OR THE REMOVAL OF KERBAND GUTTER, DETAILS OF WORKS MUST BE APPROVED BY THERMS'S ASSEST MANAGEMENT BRANCH.5NOTIFICATION TO AFFECTED BUSINESSES, RESIDENTS AND OTHERSTAKEHOLDERS MUST BE UNDERTAKEN AT LEAST 5 BUSINESS DAYSPRIOR TO WORKS COMMENCING6ROAD OCCUPANCY OFFICE AT TMC WILL BE CLOSED DURING THECHRISTMAS/NEW YEAR PERIOD FROM MONDAY 23 DECEMBER 2019TO FRIDAY 3  JANUARY 2020 (INCLUSIVE).I. THE MINIMUM 10 BUSINESS DAYS PROCESSING PERIOD WILL APPLYFROM 6 JANUARY 2020 FOR ALL NEW AND EXTENSION ROADOCCUPANCY LICENCE APPLICATIONS RECEIVED DURING THESHUTDOWN PERIOD.II. ALL EXISTING ROLS THAT EXPIRE DURING THE SHUTDOWN PERIODREQUIRING EXTENSIONS MUST BE SUBMITTED TO THIS OFFICE VIAOPLINC NO LATER THAN FRIDAY 13 DECEMBER 2019.7FOR ALL WORKS IMPACTING BUS ROUTES OR STOPS, SYDNEYCOORDINATION OFFICE, TRANSPORT INTEGRATION ARE TO BECONSULTED. PLEASE CONTACT -- FRANKIE.PASSARELLI@TMC.TRANSPORT.NSW.GOV.AU8ENSURE THE APPROPRIATE HOLD POINT IS RELEASED FOR THE TCPUSED AS PART OF THIS ROL9NO WORK 23 DEC - 03 JAN DUE TO CHRISTMAS EMBARGO10ADEQUATE ADVANCE WARNING MUST BE PROVIDED TOAPPROACHING MOTORISTS.11TRAFFIC FLOW MUST BE MAINTAINED IN BOTH DIRECTIONS AT ALLTIMES.APPROVED DATES & TIMESFrom ShiftTo ShiftFromDMTime -ToDMTimeSun01Dec07:00 -Sun01Dec18:00Mon02Dec07:00 -Mon02Dec18:00Tue03Dec07:00 -Tue03Dec18:00Wed04Dec07:00 -Wed04Dec18:00Thu05Dec07:00 -Thu05Dec18:00Fri06Dec07:00 -Fri06Dec18:00Sat07Dec07:00 -Sat07Dec18:00Sun08Dec07:00 -Sun08Dec18:00Mon09Dec07:00 -Mon09Dec18:00Tue10Dec07:00 -Tue10Dec18:00Wed11Dec07:00 -Wed11Dec18:00Thu12Dec07:00 -Thu12Dec18:00Fri13Dec07:00 -Fri13Dec18:00Sat14Dec07:00 -Sat14Dec18:00Sun15Dec07:00 -Sun15Dec18:00Mon16Dec07:00 -Mon16Dec18:00Tue17Dec07:00 -Tue17Dec18:00Wed18Dec07:00 -Wed18Dec18:00Thu19Dec07:00 -Thu19Dec18:00Fri20Dec07:00 -Fri20Dec18:00Sat21Dec07:00 -Sat21Dec18:00Sun22Dec07:00 -Sun22Dec18:00Thu02Jan07:00 -Thu02Jan18:00Sat04Jan07:00 -Sat04Jan18:00Sun05Jan07:00 -Sun05Jan18:00Mon06Jan07:00 -Mon06Jan18:00Tue07Jan07:00 -Tue07Jan18:00Wed08Jan07:00 -Wed08Jan18:00Thu09Jan07:00 -Thu09Jan18:00Fri10Jan07:00 -Fri10Jan18:00Sat11Jan07:00 -Sat11Jan18:00All pages of this Road Occupancy Licence and associated Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must beproduced for inspection when requested by representatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and otherGovernment Agencies.Page 1 of 4,ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCELICENCE NO : 1314824TRANSPORT MANAGEMENT CENTRE (TMC)Phone:  Monday To Friday 8.30 AM - 4.30 PMTo activate and deactivate your approved work shift(s) on your Road Occupancy Licence, please visit: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au. This licenceis for the occupation of the road space only. If you are unable to access myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au, please call TMC on 1800 679 782. Forfurther assistance, please refer to the proponent's user manual here: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au/help.pdfNON DEVELOPMENT - NOT KNOWNProject:WestConnex 3BThis Activity :LFR001-WB-CONTRA-Cecil to Justin ATS-WCX-3B 005LOCATIONSubject Road:LILYFIELD RDFrom:GORDON ST, ROZELLETo:GROVE ST, LILYFIELDCouncil:INNER WESTLICENSEEOrganisation:John HollandRef No:Name:Ismat ZahraPhone:0419919046ONSITE CONTACTName:Mitchell EversonPhone:0428877584TRAFFIC MANAGEMENTFlow Management:Contra Flow; Standard Lane MergeClosure Type:All lanes one directionClosure Lane(s):ShoulderDirection(s):Eastbound and WestboundLICENCE DURATIONFrom:01-Dec-2019To:31-Jan-2020LICENCE CONDITIONS12QUEUING FROM THE WORKS MUST BE MONITORED AT ALL TIMES.IF QUEUING EXTEND BEYOND 100 METRES, OR IF DELAYS EXCEED 2MINUTES ALL TRAVEL LANES MUST BE RE-OPENED UNTIL TRAFFICQUEUES ARE CLEAR AND TRAFFIC IS FREE FLOWING BEFORERESUMING THE CLOSURE.13PEDESTRIAN ACCESS MUST BE MAINTAINED AROUND THE WORKAREA IN A SAFE MANNER, COMPLYING WITH COUNCILREQUIREMENTS.14PARKING MUST BE RESTRICTED IN THE AREA SURROUNDING WORKSTO ALLOW FOR LANE OPERATION.15THIS LICENCE OPERATES IN CONJUNCTION WITH A SPEED LIMITREDUCTION TO  40 KM/H. REFER TO SZA 1314824/001APPROVED DATES & TIMESFrom ShiftTo ShiftFromDMTime -ToDMTimeSun12Jan07:00 -Sun12Jan18:00Mon13Jan07:00 -Mon13Jan18:00Tue14Jan07:00 -Tue14Jan18:00Wed15Jan07:00 -Wed15Jan18:00Thu16Jan07:00 -Thu16Jan18:00Fri17Jan07:00 -Fri17Jan18:00Sat18Jan07:00 -Sat18Jan18:00Sun19Jan07:00 -Sun19Jan18:00Mon20Jan07:00 -Mon20Jan18:00Tue21Jan07:00 -Tue21Jan18:00Wed22Jan07:00 -Wed22Jan18:00Thu23Jan07:00 -Thu23Jan18:00Fri24Jan07:00 -Fri24Jan18:00Sat25Jan07:00 -Sat25Jan18:00Sun26Jan07:00 -Sun26Jan18:00Mon27Jan07:00 -Mon27Jan18:00Tue28Jan07:00 -Tue28Jan18:00Wed29Jan07:00 -Wed29Jan18:00Thu30Jan07:00 -Thu30Jan18:00Fri31Jan07:00 -Fri31Jan18:00All pages of this Road Occupancy Licence and associated Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must beproduced for inspection when requested by representatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and otherGovernment Agencies.Page 2 of 4,All pages of this Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must be produced for inspection when requested byrepresentatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and other Government Agencies.Page 3 of 4,All pages of this Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must be produced for inspection when requested byrepresentatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and other Government Agencies.Page 4 of 4'''
output2 = '''ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCELICENCE NO : 1314782TRANSPORT MANAGEMENT CENTRE (TMC)Phone:  Monday To Friday 8.30 AM - 4.30 PMTo activate and deactivate your approved work shift(s) on your Road Occupancy Licence, please visit: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au. This licenceis for the occupation of the road space only. If you are unable to access myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au, please call TMC on 1800 679 782. Forfurther assistance, please refer to the proponent's user manual here: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au/help.pdfNON DEVELOPMENT - NOT KNOWNProject:WestConnex 3BThis Activity :VR011-E-2of4-S-Iron Cove to Wellington ATS-WCX3B 056 CombinedLOCATIONSubject Road:VICTORIA RDFrom:HENLEY MARINE DR, DRUMMOYNETo:WELLINGTON ST, ROZELLECouncil:CANADA BAYLICENSEEOrganisation:John HollandRef No:Name:Ismat ZahraPhone:0419919046ONSITE CONTACTName:Mitchell EversonPhone:0428877584TRAFFIC MANAGEMENTFlow Management:Standard Lane MergeClosure Type:2 lanes of 3Closure Lane(s):Lane 1 (kerb lane/s); Lane 2 (next after kerb lane)Direction(s):SouthboundLICENCE DURATIONFrom:01-Dec-2019To:01-Feb-2020LICENCE CONDITIONS1YOU MUST USE SHIFT ACTIVATION WEB ADDRESShttps://myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au TO ACTIVATE AND DEACTIVATE YOURAPPROVED ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCE(S). (TO CHANGE TRAFFICCONTROL SIGNALS TO FLASHING YELLOW OR TO ACTIVATEPERMANENT VARIABLE MESSAGE SIGNS DIAL 1800 679 782)2THIS LICENCE IS NOT AN APPROVAL OF THE PROPONENT'S TRAFFICCONTROL PLAN. PLEASE NOTE WORKCOVER REQUIRES THATTRAFFIC CONTROL PLANS COMPLY WITH AS1742.33ALL MATTERS RELATING TO NOISE GENERATION OR OTHERENVIRONMENTAL FACTORS ON SITE ARE UNDER THE JURISDRICTIONOF THE LOCAL COUNCIL AND/OR THE ENVIRONMENTAL PROTECTIONAUTHORITY.4SHOULD THE PROPOSED WORKS INVOLVE UNDERBORING OREXCAVATION OF STATE ROAD ASSETS OR THE REMOVAL OF KERBAND GUTTER, DETAILS OF WORKS MUST BE APPROVED BY THERMS'S ASSEST MANAGEMENT BRANCH.5NOTIFICATION TO AFFECTED BUSINESSES, RESIDENTS AND OTHERSTAKEHOLDERS MUST BE UNDERTAKEN AT LEAST 5 BUSINESS DAYSPRIOR TO WORKS COMMENCING6ROAD OCCUPANCY OFFICE AT TMC WILL BE CLOSED DURING THECHRISTMAS/NEW YEAR PERIOD FROM MONDAY 23 DECEMBER 2019TO FRIDAY 3  JANUARY 2020 (INCLUSIVE).I. THE MINIMUM 10 BUSINESS DAYS PROCESSING PERIOD WILL APPLYFROM 6 JANUARY 2020 FOR ALL NEW AND EXTENSION ROADOCCUPANCY LICENCE APPLICATIONS RECEIVED DURING THESHUTDOWN PERIOD.II. ALL EXISTING ROLS THAT EXPIRE DURING THE SHUTDOWN PERIODREQUIRING EXTENSIONS MUST BE SUBMITTED TO THIS OFFICE VIAOPLINC NO LATER THAN FRIDAY 13 DECEMBER 2019.7FOR ALL WORKS IMPACTING BUS ROUTES OR STOPS, SYDNEYCOORDINATION OFFICE, TRANSPORT INTEGRATION ARE TO BECONSULTED. PLEASE CONTACT -- FRANKIE.PASSARELLI@TMC.TRANSPORT.NSW.GOV.AU8ENSURE THE APPROPRIATE HOLD POINT IS RELEASED FOR THE TCPUSED AS PART OF THIS ROL9NO WORK 23 DEC - 03 JAN DUE TO CHRISTMAS EMBARGO10WORKSITE MUST BE SETUP TO ENSURE ONE (1) TRAFFICABLE LANEREMAINS OPEN TO TRAFFIC AT ALL TIMES IN EACH DIRECTION. LANEWIDTHS MUST BE SUFFICIENT TO PERMIT HEAVY VEHICLES ACCESS.11ADEQUATE ADVANCE WARNING MUST BE PROVIDED TOAPPROACHING MOTORISTS.12EXISTING BUS STOPS IN WORK AREA MUST BE MAINTAINED INCONSULTATION WITH ALL BUS COMPANIES USING THESE STOPS.APPROVED DATES & TIMESFrom ShiftTo ShiftFromDMTime -ToDMTimeSun01Dec21:00 -Mon02Dec05:00Mon02Dec21:00 -Tue03Dec05:00Tue03Dec22:00 -Wed04Dec05:00Wed04Dec22:00 -Thu05Dec05:00Thu05Dec22:00 -Fri06Dec05:00Fri06Dec22:00 -Sat07Dec06:00Sat07Dec22:00 -Sun08Dec06:00Sun08Dec21:00 -Mon09Dec05:00Mon09Dec21:00 -Tue10Dec05:00Tue10Dec22:00 -Wed11Dec05:00Wed11Dec22:00 -Thu12Dec05:00Thu12Dec22:00 -Fri13Dec05:00Fri13Dec22:00 -Sat14Dec06:00Sat14Dec22:00 -Sun15Dec06:00Sun15Dec21:00 -Mon16Dec05:00Mon16Dec21:00 -Tue17Dec05:00Tue17Dec22:00 -Wed18Dec05:00Wed18Dec22:00 -Thu19Dec05:00Thu19Dec22:00 -Fri20Dec05:00Fri20Dec22:00 -Sat21Dec06:00Sat21Dec22:00 -Sun22Dec06:00Sun22Dec21:00 -Mon23Dec05:00Sat04Jan22:00 -Sun05Jan06:00Sun05Jan21:00 -Mon06Jan05:00Mon06Jan21:00 -Tue07Jan05:00Tue07Jan22:00 -Wed08Jan05:00Wed08Jan22:00 -Thu09Jan05:00Thu09Jan22:00 -Fri10Jan05:00Fri10Jan22:00 -Sat11Jan06:00Sat11Jan22:00 -Sun12Jan06:00Sun12Jan21:00 -Mon13Jan05:00All pages of this Road Occupancy Licence and associated Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must beproduced for inspection when requested by representatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and otherGovernment Agencies.Page 1 of 4,ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCELICENCE NO : 1314782TRANSPORT MANAGEMENT CENTRE (TMC)Phone:  Monday To Friday 8.30 AM - 4.30 PMTo activate and deactivate your approved work shift(s) on your Road Occupancy Licence, please visit: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au. This licenceis for the occupation of the road space only. If you are unable to access myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au, please call TMC on 1800 679 782. Forfurther assistance, please refer to the proponent's user manual here: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au/help.pdfNON DEVELOPMENT - NOT KNOWNProject:WestConnex 3BThis Activity :VR011-E-2of4-S-Iron Cove to Wellington ATS-WCX3B 056 CombinedLOCATIONSubject Road:VICTORIA RDFrom:HENLEY MARINE DR, DRUMMOYNETo:WELLINGTON ST, ROZELLECouncil:CANADA BAYLICENSEEOrganisation:John HollandRef No:Name:Ismat ZahraPhone:0419919046ONSITE CONTACTName:Mitchell EversonPhone:0428877584TRAFFIC MANAGEMENTFlow Management:Standard Lane MergeClosure Type:2 lanes of 3Closure Lane(s):Lane 1 (kerb lane/s); Lane 2 (next after kerb lane)Direction(s):SouthboundLICENCE DURATIONFrom:01-Dec-2019To:01-Feb-2020LICENCE CONDITIONS13QUEUING FROM THE WORKS MUST BE MONITORED AT ALL TIMES.IF QUEUING EXTEND BEYOND 100 METRES, OR IF DELAYS EXCEED 2MINUTES ALL TRAVEL LANES MUST BE RE-OPENED UNTIL TRAFFICQUEUES ARE CLEAR AND TRAFFIC IS FREE FLOWING BEFORERESUMING THE CLOSURE.14PEDESTRIAN ACCESS MUST BE MAINTAINED AROUND THE WORKAREA IN A SAFE MANNER, COMPLYING WITH COUNCILREQUIREMENTS.15SIGNAL OPERATIONS MUST BE DISCUSSED WITH TMC PRIOR TOUNDERTAKING CLOSURE.16THIS LICENCE OPERATES IN CONJUNCTION WITH A SPEED LIMITREDUCTION TO  40 KM/H. REFER TO SZA 1314782/00117CLOSE CONTACT MUST BE MAINTAINED WITH TRANSPORTMANAGEMENT CENTRE ON 1300 725 886 DURING THE WORKS.APPROVED DATES & TIMESFrom ShiftTo ShiftFromDMTime -ToDMTimeMon13Jan21:00 -Tue14Jan05:00Tue14Jan22:00 -Wed15Jan05:00Wed15Jan22:00 -Thu16Jan05:00Thu16Jan22:00 -Fri17Jan05:00Fri17Jan22:00 -Sat18Jan06:00Sat18Jan22:00 -Sun19Jan06:00Sun19Jan21:00 -Mon20Jan05:00Mon20Jan21:00 -Tue21Jan05:00Tue21Jan22:00 -Wed22Jan05:00Wed22Jan22:00 -Thu23Jan05:00Thu23Jan22:00 -Fri24Jan05:00Fri24Jan22:00 -Sat25Jan06:00Sat25Jan22:00 -Sun26Jan06:00Sun26Jan21:00 -Mon27Jan05:00Mon27Jan21:00 -Tue28Jan05:00Tue28Jan22:00 -Wed29Jan05:00Wed29Jan22:00 -Thu30Jan05:00Thu30Jan22:00 -Fri31Jan05:00Fri31Jan22:00 -Sat01Feb06:00All pages of this Road Occupancy Licence and associated Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must beproduced for inspection when requested by representatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and otherGovernment Agencies.Page 2 of 4,All pages of this Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must be produced for inspection when requested byrepresentatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and other Government Agencies.Page 3 of 4,All pages of this Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must be produced for inspection when requested byrepresentatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and other Government Agencies.Page 4 of 4'''
output3 = '''ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCELICENCE NO : 1314796TRANSPORT MANAGEMENT CENTRE (TMC)Phone:  Monday To Friday 8.30 AM - 4.30 PMTo activate and deactivate your approved work shift(s) on your Road Occupancy Licence, please visit: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au. This licenceis for the occupation of the road space only. If you are unable to access myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au, please call TMC on 1800 679 782. Forfurther assistance, please refer to the proponent's user manual here: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au/help.pdfNON DEVELOPMENT - NOT KNOWNProject:WestConnex 3BThis Activity :VR011-E-2of4-S-Iron Cove to Wellington ATS-WCX3B 054 CombinedLOCATIONSubject Road:VICTORIA RDFrom:HENLEY MARINE DR, DRUMMOYNETo:WELLINGTON ST, ROZELLECouncil:CANADA BAYLICENSEEOrganisation:John HollandRef No:Name:Ismat ZahraPhone:0419919046ONSITE CONTACTName:Mitchell EversonPhone:0428877584TRAFFIC MANAGEMENTFlow Management:Standard Lane MergeClosure Type:1 lane of 3Closure Lane(s):Lane 1 (kerb lane/s); Lane 3Direction(s):SouthboundLICENCE DURATIONFrom:01-Dec-2019To:31-Jan-2020LICENCE CONDITIONS1YOU MUST USE SHIFT ACTIVATION WEB ADDRESShttps://myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au TO ACTIVATE AND DEACTIVATE YOURAPPROVED ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCE(S). (TO CHANGE TRAFFICCONTROL SIGNALS TO FLASHING YELLOW OR TO ACTIVATEPERMANENT VARIABLE MESSAGE SIGNS DIAL 1800 679 782)2THIS LICENCE IS NOT AN APPROVAL OF THE PROPONENT'S TRAFFICCONTROL PLAN. PLEASE NOTE WORKCOVER REQUIRES THATTRAFFIC CONTROL PLANS COMPLY WITH AS1742.33ALL MATTERS RELATING TO NOISE GENERATION OR OTHERENVIRONMENTAL FACTORS ON SITE ARE UNDER THE JURISDRICTIONOF THE LOCAL COUNCIL AND/OR THE ENVIRONMENTAL PROTECTIONAUTHORITY.4SHOULD THE PROPOSED WORKS INVOLVE UNDERBORING OREXCAVATION OF STATE ROAD ASSETS OR THE REMOVAL OF KERBAND GUTTER, DETAILS OF WORKS MUST BE APPROVED BY THERMS'S ASSEST MANAGEMENT BRANCH.5NOTIFICATION TO AFFECTED BUSINESSES, RESIDENTS AND OTHERSTAKEHOLDERS MUST BE UNDERTAKEN AT LEAST 5 BUSINESS DAYSPRIOR TO WORKS COMMENCING6ROAD OCCUPANCY OFFICE AT TMC WILL BE CLOSED DURING THECHRISTMAS/NEW YEAR PERIOD FROM MONDAY 23 DECEMBER 2019TO FRIDAY 3  JANUARY 2020 (INCLUSIVE).I. THE MINIMUM 10 BUSINESS DAYS PROCESSING PERIOD WILL APPLYFROM 6 JANUARY 2020 FOR ALL NEW AND EXTENSION ROADOCCUPANCY LICENCE APPLICATIONS RECEIVED DURING THESHUTDOWN PERIOD.II. ALL EXISTING ROLS THAT EXPIRE DURING THE SHUTDOWN PERIODREQUIRING EXTENSIONS MUST BE SUBMITTED TO THIS OFFICE VIAOPLINC NO LATER THAN FRIDAY 13 DECEMBER 2019.7FOR ALL WORKS IMPACTING BUS ROUTES OR STOPS, SYDNEYCOORDINATION OFFICE, TRANSPORT INTEGRATION ARE TO BECONSULTED. PLEASE CONTACT -- FRANKIE.PASSARELLI@TMC.TRANSPORT.NSW.GOV.AU8NO WORK 23 DEC - 03 JAN DUE TO CHRISTMAS EMBARGO9ENSURE THE APPROPRIATE HOLD POINT IS RELEASED FOR THE TCPUSED AS PART OF THIS ROL10TWO (2) TRAFFICABLE LANES MUST REMAIN OPEN TO TRAFFIC ATALL TIMES. LANE WIDTHS MUST BE SUFFICIENT TO PERMIT HEAVYVEHICLES ACCESS.11ADEQUATE ADVANCE WARNING MUST BE PROVIDED TOAPPROACHING MOTORISTS.12EXISTING BUS STOPS IN WORK AREA MUST BE MAINTAINED INCONSULTATION WITH ALL BUS COMPANIES USING THESE STOPS.APPROVED DATES & TIMESFrom ShiftTo ShiftFromDMTime -ToDMTimeSun01Dec07:00 -Sun01Dec17:00Mon02Dec10:00 -Mon02Dec15:00Tue03Dec10:00 -Tue03Dec15:00Wed04Dec10:00 -Wed04Dec15:00Thu05Dec10:00 -Thu05Dec15:00Fri06Dec10:00 -Fri06Dec15:00Sat07Dec07:00 -Sat07Dec17:00Sun08Dec07:00 -Sun08Dec17:00Mon09Dec10:00 -Mon09Dec15:00Tue10Dec10:00 -Tue10Dec15:00Wed11Dec10:00 -Wed11Dec15:00Thu12Dec10:00 -Thu12Dec15:00Fri13Dec10:00 -Fri13Dec15:00Sat14Dec07:00 -Sat14Dec17:00Sun15Dec07:00 -Sun15Dec17:00Mon16Dec10:00 -Mon16Dec15:00Tue17Dec10:00 -Tue17Dec15:00Wed18Dec10:00 -Wed18Dec15:00Thu19Dec10:00 -Thu19Dec15:00Fri20Dec10:00 -Fri20Dec15:00Sat21Dec07:00 -Sat21Dec17:00Sun22Dec07:00 -Sun22Dec17:00Sat04Jan07:00 -Sat04Jan17:00Sun05Jan07:00 -Sun05Jan17:00Mon06Jan10:00 -Mon06Jan15:00Tue07Jan10:00 -Tue07Jan15:00Wed08Jan10:00 -Wed08Jan15:00Thu09Jan10:00 -Thu09Jan15:00Fri10Jan10:00 -Fri10Jan15:00Sat11Jan07:00 -Sat11Jan17:00Sun12Jan07:00 -Sun12Jan17:00All pages of this Road Occupancy Licence and associated Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must beproduced for inspection when requested by representatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and otherGovernment Agencies.Page 1 of 4,ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCELICENCE NO : 1314796TRANSPORT MANAGEMENT CENTRE (TMC)Phone:  Monday To Friday 8.30 AM - 4.30 PMTo activate and deactivate your approved work shift(s) on your Road Occupancy Licence, please visit: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au. This licenceis for the occupation of the road space only. If you are unable to access myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au, please call TMC on 1800 679 782. Forfurther assistance, please refer to the proponent's user manual here: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au/help.pdfNON DEVELOPMENT - NOT KNOWNProject:WestConnex 3BThis Activity :VR011-E-2of4-S-Iron Cove to Wellington ATS-WCX3B 054 CombinedLOCATIONSubject Road:VICTORIA RDFrom:HENLEY MARINE DR, DRUMMOYNETo:WELLINGTON ST, ROZELLECouncil:CANADA BAYLICENSEEOrganisation:John HollandRef No:Name:Ismat ZahraPhone:0419919046ONSITE CONTACTName:Mitchell EversonPhone:0428877584TRAFFIC MANAGEMENTFlow Management:Standard Lane MergeClosure Type:1 lane of 3Closure Lane(s):Lane 1 (kerb lane/s); Lane 3Direction(s):SouthboundLICENCE DURATIONFrom:01-Dec-2019To:31-Jan-2020LICENCE CONDITIONS13QUEUING FROM THE WORKS MUST BE MONITORED AT ALL TIMES.IF QUEUING EXTEND BEYOND 100 METRES, OR IF DELAYS EXCEED 2MINUTES ALL TRAVEL LANES MUST BE RE-OPENED UNTIL TRAFFICQUEUES ARE CLEAR AND TRAFFIC IS FREE FLOWING BEFORERESUMING THE CLOSURE.14PEDESTRIAN ACCESS MUST BE MAINTAINED AROUND THE WORKAREA IN A SAFE MANNER, COMPLYING WITH COUNCILREQUIREMENTS.15THIS LICENCE OPERATES IN CONJUNCTION WITH A SPEED LIMITREDUCTION TO 40 KM/H. REFER TO SZA 1314796/00116CLOSE CONTACT MUST BE MAINTAINED WITH TRANSPORTMANAGEMENT CENTRE ON 1300 725 886 DURING THE WORKS.APPROVED DATES & TIMESFrom ShiftTo ShiftFromDMTime -ToDMTimeMon13Jan10:00 -Mon13Jan15:00Tue14Jan10:00 -Tue14Jan15:00Wed15Jan10:00 -Wed15Jan15:00Thu16Jan10:00 -Thu16Jan15:00Fri17Jan10:00 -Fri17Jan15:00Sat18Jan07:00 -Sat18Jan17:00Sun19Jan07:00 -Sun19Jan17:00Mon20Jan10:00 -Mon20Jan15:00Tue21Jan10:00 -Tue21Jan15:00Wed22Jan10:00 -Wed22Jan15:00Thu23Jan10:00 -Thu23Jan15:00Fri24Jan10:00 -Fri24Jan15:00Sat25Jan07:00 -Sat25Jan17:00Sun26Jan07:00 -Sun26Jan17:00Mon27Jan10:00 -Mon27Jan15:00Tue28Jan10:00 -Tue28Jan15:00Wed29Jan10:00 -Wed29Jan15:00Thu30Jan10:00 -Thu30Jan15:00Fri31Jan10:00 -Fri31Jan15:00All pages of this Road Occupancy Licence and associated Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must beproduced for inspection when requested by representatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and otherGovernment Agencies.Page 2 of 4,All pages of this Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must be produced for inspection when requested byrepresentatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and other Government Agencies.Page 3 of 4,All pages of this Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must be produced for inspection when requested byrepresentatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and other Government Agencies.Page 4 of 4'''
output4 = '''ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCELICENCE NO : 1314814TRANSPORT MANAGEMENT CENTRE (TMC)Phone:  Monday To Friday 8.30 AM - 4.30 PMTo activate and deactivate your approved work shift(s) on your Road Occupancy Licence, please visit: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au. This licenceis for the occupation of the road space only. If you are unable to access myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au, please call TMC on 1800 679 782. Forfurther assistance, please refer to the proponent's user manual here: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au/help.pdfNON DEVELOPMENT - NOT KNOWNProject:WestConnex 3BThis Activity :VR022-WB-1 of 3 S-Hornsey to Quirk  + EBHornsey Lane Closure-ATS-WCX-3B-134CombinedLOCATIONSubject Road:QUIRK STFrom:VICTORIA RD, ROZELLETo:GRAHAM ST, ROZELLECouncil:INNER WESTLICENSEEOrganisation:John HollandRef No:Name:Ismat ZahraPhone:0419919046ONSITE CONTACTName:Mitchell EversonPhone:0428877584TRAFFIC MANAGEMENTFlow Management:Detour (other roads)Closure Type:All lanes one directionClosure Lane(s):Shoulder; Median ShoulderDirection(s):WestboundLICENCE DURATIONFrom:01-Dec-2019To:01-Feb-2020LICENCE CONDITIONS1YOU MUST USE SHIFT ACTIVATION WEB ADDRESShttps://myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au TO ACTIVATE AND DEACTIVATE YOURAPPROVED ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCE(S). (TO CHANGE TRAFFICCONTROL SIGNALS TO FLASHING YELLOW OR TO ACTIVATEPERMANENT VARIABLE MESSAGE SIGNS DIAL 1800 679 782)2THIS LICENCE IS NOT AN APPROVAL OF THE PROPONENT'S TRAFFICCONTROL PLAN. PLEASE NOTE WORKCOVER REQUIRES THATTRAFFIC CONTROL PLANS COMPLY WITH AS1742.33ALL MATTERS RELATING TO NOISE GENERATION OR OTHERENVIRONMENTAL FACTORS ON SITE ARE UNDER THE JURISDRICTIONOF THE LOCAL COUNCIL AND/OR THE ENVIRONMENTAL PROTECTIONAUTHORITY.4SHOULD THE PROPOSED WORKS INVOLVE UNDERBORING OREXCAVATION OF STATE ROAD ASSETS OR THE REMOVAL OF KERBAND GUTTER, DETAILS OF WORKS MUST BE APPROVED BY THERMS'S ASSEST MANAGEMENT BRANCH.5NOTIFICATION TO AFFECTED BUSINESSES, RESIDENTS AND OTHERSTAKEHOLDERS MUST BE UNDERTAKEN AT LEAST 5 BUSINESS DAYSPRIOR TO WORKS COMMENCING6ROAD OCCUPANCY OFFICE AT TMC WILL BE CLOSED DURING THECHRISTMAS/NEW YEAR PERIOD FROM MONDAY 23 DECEMBER 2019TO FRIDAY 3  JANUARY 2020 (INCLUSIVE).I. THE MINIMUM 10 BUSINESS DAYS PROCESSING PERIOD WILL APPLYFROM 6 JANUARY 2020 FOR ALL NEW AND EXTENSION ROADOCCUPANCY LICENCE APPLICATIONS RECEIVED DURING THESHUTDOWN PERIOD.II. ALL EXISTING ROLS THAT EXPIRE DURING THE SHUTDOWN PERIODREQUIRING EXTENSIONS MUST BE SUBMITTED TO THIS OFFICE VIAOPLINC NO LATER THAN FRIDAY 13 DECEMBER 2019.7FOR ALL WORKS IMPACTING BUS ROUTES OR STOPS, SYDNEYCOORDINATION OFFICE, TRANSPORT INTEGRATION ARE TO BECONSULTED. PLEASE CONTACT -- FRANKIE.PASSARELLI@TMC.TRANSPORT.NSW.GOV.AU8ENSURE THE APPROPRIATE HOLD POINT IS RELEASED FOR THE TCPUSED AS PART OF THIS ROL9NO WORK 23 DEC - 03 JAN DUE TO CHRISTMAS EMBARGO10ADEQUATE ADVANCE WARNING MUST BE PROVIDED TOAPPROACHING MOTORISTS.11DETOUR ROUTE MUST BE CLEARLY SIGNPOSTED.12PEDESTRIAN ACCESS MUST BE MAINTAINED AROUND THE WORKAREA IN A SAFE MANNER, COMPLYING WITH COUNCILREQUIREMENTS.13LOCAL RESIDENT ACCESS MUST BE MAINTAINED AT ALL TIMES.APPROVED DATES & TIMESFrom ShiftTo ShiftFromDMTime -ToDMTimeSun01Dec20:00 -Mon02Dec04:30Mon02Dec20:00 -Tue03Dec04:30Tue03Dec22:00 -Wed04Dec04:30Wed04Dec22:00 -Thu05Dec04:30Thu05Dec22:00 -Fri06Dec04:30Fri06Dec23:00 -Sat07Dec06:00Sat07Dec23:30 -Sun08Dec07:00Sun08Dec20:00 -Mon09Dec04:30Mon09Dec20:00 -Tue10Dec04:30Tue10Dec22:00 -Wed11Dec04:30Wed11Dec22:00 -Thu12Dec04:30Thu12Dec22:00 -Fri13Dec04:30Fri13Dec23:00 -Sat14Dec06:00Sat14Dec23:30 -Sun15Dec07:00Sun15Dec20:00 -Mon16Dec04:30Mon16Dec20:00 -Tue17Dec04:30Tue17Dec22:00 -Wed18Dec04:30Wed18Dec22:00 -Thu19Dec04:30Thu19Dec22:00 -Fri20Dec04:30Fri20Dec23:00 -Sat21Dec06:00Sat21Dec23:30 -Sun22Dec07:00Sun22Dec20:00 -Mon23Dec04:30Sat04Jan23:30 -Sun05Jan07:00Sun05Jan20:00 -Mon06Jan04:30Mon06Jan20:00 -Tue07Jan04:30Tue07Jan22:00 -Wed08Jan04:30Wed08Jan22:00 -Thu09Jan04:30Thu09Jan22:00 -Fri10Jan04:30Fri10Jan23:00 -Sat11Jan06:00Sat11Jan23:30 -Sun12Jan07:00Sun12Jan20:00 -Mon13Jan04:30All pages of this Road Occupancy Licence and associated Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must beproduced for inspection when requested by representatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and otherGovernment Agencies.Page 1 of 2,ROAD OCCUPANCY LICENCELICENCE NO : 1314814TRANSPORT MANAGEMENT CENTRE (TMC)Phone:  Monday To Friday 8.30 AM - 4.30 PMTo activate and deactivate your approved work shift(s) on your Road Occupancy Licence, please visit: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au. This licenceis for the occupation of the road space only. If you are unable to access myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au, please call TMC on 1800 679 782. Forfurther assistance, please refer to the proponent's user manual here: myrol.transport.nsw.gov.au/help.pdfNON DEVELOPMENT - NOT KNOWNProject:WestConnex 3BThis Activity :VR022-WB-1 of 3 S-Hornsey to Quirk  + EBHornsey Lane Closure-ATS-WCX-3B-134CombinedLOCATIONSubject Road:QUIRK STFrom:VICTORIA RD, ROZELLETo:GRAHAM ST, ROZELLECouncil:INNER WESTLICENSEEOrganisation:John HollandRef No:Name:Ismat ZahraPhone:0419919046ONSITE CONTACTName:Mitchell EversonPhone:0428877584TRAFFIC MANAGEMENTFlow Management:Detour (other roads)Closure Type:All lanes one directionClosure Lane(s):Shoulder; Median ShoulderDirection(s):WestboundLICENCE DURATIONFrom:01-Dec-2019To:01-Feb-2020APPROVED DATES & TIMESFrom ShiftTo ShiftFromDMTime -ToDMTimeMon13Jan20:00 -Tue14Jan04:30Tue14Jan22:00 -Wed15Jan04:30Wed15Jan22:00 -Thu16Jan04:30Thu16Jan22:00 -Fri17Jan04:30Fri17Jan23:00 -Sat18Jan06:00Sat18Jan23:30 -Sun19Jan07:00Sun19Jan20:00 -Mon20Jan04:30Mon20Jan20:00 -Tue21Jan04:30Tue21Jan22:00 -Wed22Jan04:30Wed22Jan22:00 -Thu23Jan04:30Thu23Jan22:00 -Fri24Jan04:30Fri24Jan23:00 -Sat25Jan06:00Sat25Jan23:30 -Sun26Jan07:00Sun26Jan20:00 -Mon27Jan04:30Mon27Jan20:00 -Tue28Jan04:30Tue28Jan22:00 -Wed29Jan04:30Wed29Jan22:00 -Thu30Jan04:30Thu30Jan22:00 -Fri31Jan04:30Fri31Jan23:00 -Sat01Feb06:00All pages of this Road Occupancy Licence and associated Speed Zone Authorisation(s) must be available on site at all times and must beproduced for inspection when requested by representatives of NSW Police, Roads & Maritimes Services, Transport for NSW and otherGovernment Agencies.Page 2 of 2'''
```

See below for whole code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import PyPDF2
import sys
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

'''Purge duplicates by finding copies and download duplicates'''
file_path = 'C:/Users/ipeter/Desktop/Webdriverdownloads'
dupfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,'*(1).pdf'))
copfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,'*Copy.pdf'))
copfiles.extend(dupfiles)

for file in copfiles:
        os.remove(file)

'''ROLS only'''
read_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,'ROL_*.pdf'))

'''Regex Compile objects for looping through string''' 
REGEXstart = re.compile(r'DURATIONFrom:(\d\d-\w\w\w-\d\d\d\d)To:')
REGEXfinish = re.compile(r'To:(\d\d-\w\w\w-\d\d\d\d)LICENCE')
REGEXrolnum = re.compile(r'LICENCELICENCE NO : (\d{7})')
REGEXroad = re.compile(r'Subject Road:([ -~]*?)From')
REGEXfrom = re.compile(r'From:([ -~]*?)To:')
REGEXTo = re.compile(r'To:([ -~]*?)Council:')
REGEXFlow = re.compile(r'Flow Management:([ -~]*?)Closure Type:')
REGEXdirection = re.compile(r'Direction\(s\):(\w+[ \w+]*?)LICENCE')
REGEXyear = re.compile(r'DURATIONFrom:\d\d-\w\w\w-(\d\d\d\d)To:')
REGEXclosureT = re.compile(r'Closure Type:([ -~]*?)Closure Lane')
REGEXclosureL = re.compile(r'Closure Lane\(s\):([ -~]*?)Direction')
'''ROL Shift times'''
REGEXshiftstartday = re.compile(r'(\w{3})\d{2}\w{3}\d{2}:\d{2}\s-')
REGEXshiftfinishday = re.compile(r'\s-(\w{3})\d{2}\w{3}\d{2}:\d{2}')
REGEXshiftstartdate = re.compile(r'\w{3}(\d{2}\w{3})\d{2}:\d{2}\s-')
REGEXshiftfinishdate = re.compile(r'\s-\w{3}(\d{2}\w{3})\d{2}:\d{2}')
REGEXshiftstarttime = re.compile(r'\w{3}\d{2}\w{3}(\d{2}:\d{2})\s-')
REGEXshiftfinishtime = re.compile(r'\s-\w{3}\d{2}\w{3}(\d{2}:\d{2})')

'''This generator is workaround for pandas dataframe of equal length columns'''
def Growinglist(selection, longlength):
    while len(selection)<longlength:
        selection.append(selection[0])

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

'''NESTED LOOP = Read all pdf files in folder. Then read all pages. Return list'''

#How to create generator for these loops using re.compile objects define above?
for files in read_files:
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(files)
    count = pdfReader.numPages
    logging.debug(read_files.index(files))
    output = []
    for i in range(count):
        page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
        output.append(page.extractText())

    output = ','.join(output)#joins each element into single string
    rolnum = [REGEXrolnum.search(output)[1]]
    start = [REGEXstart.search(output)[1]]#LICENCE START DATE
    finish = [REGEXfinish.search(output)[1]]#LICENCE FINISH DATE
    road = [REGEXroad.search(output)[1]]#SUBJECT ROAD
    From = [REGEXfrom.search(output)[1]]#FROM ROAD
    To = [REGEXTo.search(output)[1]]#TO ROAD
    Flow = [REGEXFlow.search(output)[1]]
    direction = [REGEXdirection.search(output)[1]]
    closureT = [REGEXclosureT.search(output)[1]]
    closureL = [REGEXclosureL.search(output)[1]]
    year = REGEXyear.search(output)[1]

    shiftstartday = REGEXshiftstartday.findall(output)#SHIFT START DAY
    shiftfinishday = REGEXshiftfinishday.findall(output)#SHIFT FINISH DAY
    shiftstartdate = REGEXshiftstartdate.findall(output)#SHIFT START DATE
    shiftfinishdate = REGEXshiftfinishdate.findall(output)#SHIFT FINISH DATE
    shiftstarttime = REGEXshiftstarttime.findall(output)#SHIFT START TIME
    shiftfinishtime = REGEXshiftfinishtime.findall(output)#SHIFT FINISH TIME

    shiftstartdate = [item + year for item in shiftstartdate]
    shiftfinishdate = [item + year for item in shiftfinishdate]

    '''Create list to compare lengths of each. Find longest and match length with others'''
    ##I know this is very inefficient. How to improve?
    lists = [rolnum,start,finish,road,From,To,direction,shiftstartday,shiftfinishday,shiftstartdate,shiftfinishdate,shiftstarttime,shiftfinishtime]
    longlength = len(max(lists, key=len))

    Growinglist(rolnum,longlength)
    Growinglist(start,longlength)
    Growinglist(finish,longlength)
    Growinglist(road,longlength)
    Growinglist(From,longlength)
    Growinglist(To,longlength)
    Growinglist(Flow,longlength)
    Growinglist(closureT,longlength)
    Growinglist(closureL,longlength)
    Growinglist(direction,longlength)

    print('\n\n', 'Stripped pdf from ROL: ' + rolnum[0])

    '''Append each pdf scraped data onto existing dataframe df1'''
    d = {'ROL #' : rolnum, 'SUBJECT RD' : road,'FROM RD' : From,'TO RD' : To,'FLOW MANAGEMENT':Flow,'CLOSURE TYPE' : closureT,'CLOSURE LANE': closureL, 'LICENCE START DATE' : start, 'LICENCE FINISH DATE' : finish, 'SHIFT START DATE' : shiftstartdate, 'SHIFT FINISH DATE' : shiftfinishdate, 'SHIFT START DAY' : shiftstartday, 'SHIFT FINISH DAY' : shiftfinishday,'SHIFT START TIME' : shiftstarttime, 'SHIFT FINISH TIME' : shiftfinishtime,'DIRECTION' : direction}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
    df1 = df1.append(df, ignore_index=True)

df1.to_excel('C:/Users/ipeter/Desktop/Webdriverdownloads/ROL data (NEMO).xlsx', sheet_name='APPROVED ROL')

print('\n', 'NEMO program was executed: ' + str(datetime.now()))
```

### Problems

- All lists must be of equal length. I'm not familiar with tuples so
  have grouped regex objects as lists. This makes easier to input to
  Dataframe using `Growing()` generator too.
- Can I iterate regex
  objects over pdf files using a generator? Current for loop is clunky.
- These regex search methods are positional i.e they are based on pdf format not changing and for each `output` string and position of elements within the string. I know this isn't recommended but works for my situation.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.